# Apache Spark and Zookeeper multi-region deployment?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Has anyone been using apache spark on multi-region?

We are building an application that must be multi-region deployed. Our stack is basically Scala, Spark, Cassandra and Kafka. The main goal is to use Spark streaming with Kafka and insert it on Cassandra.

Reading the Spark documentation, Zookeeper is needed to keep high availability as well as in Kafka.

The question is: Should I consider keep a spark cluster on each region or should I use like cassandra? Since it depends on zookeeper to keep high availability on master nodes, how about that? The same applies to zookeeper or not?